# How to use CancellationToken from one class to another class gracefully?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, synchronization

I have a long running operation in my Winforms project. I am calling a long running synchronization operation from one to another class.
So, In Class1, I am performing a single run of the synchronization operation and calling `synchronizer.Synchronize();` which is implemented in `Class2`.
Any type of MemberShipSynchronization service interupption or Stopped is disposed in Class1 in its `Dispose()`.

From `Class2`, I am calling the `populator.PopulateMembership();` which is implemented in `Class3`, So, the `PopulateMembership()` in class3 is long running process.

I want to make this operation `Cancellable`, means, I want to send the `CancellableToken` from Class1 to Class3 based on MemberShipSynchronization Service request ( i.e. Stop/Interuppted) and
when the long running operation in `Class3` receive the Cancellation request that time I want to Cancel this operation.
So finally, I want to handle this operation gracefully in `Class1`.
Please suggest a better workaround to achieve this.

**=>Class1.**

```
public sealed class MembershipSynchronizationService : IDisposable
{
   private readonly object _sync = new object();

   /// <summary>
  /// Performs a single run of the synchronization service.
  /// </summary>
  public void RunOnce()
  {
     lock (_sync)
     {
        var synchronizer = new MembershipSynchronizer(MembershipManagerUnsecured.SoleInstance.MembershipManager);
        synchronizer.Synchronize();
     }
  }

  #region Dispose pattern

  /// <summary>
  /// Finalizer.  Cleans up resources.
  /// </summary>
  ~MembershipSynchronizationService()
  {
     Dispose(false);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Cleans up resources.
  /// </summary>
  public void Dispose()
  {
     Dispose(true);
     GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Cleans up resources.
  /// </summary>
  private void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
     if (disposing)
     {
        lock (_sync)
        {
           // nothing to do
           _ = this;
        }
     }
  }

  #endregion

}
```

**=> Class2.**

```
internal sealed class MembershipSynchronizer
{
   /// <summary>
  /// Performs a single run of the synchronization service.
  /// </summary>
  public void Synchronize()
  { 
     try
     {
        TimeSpan elapsed;
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

       var populator = _membershipPopulatorFactory.CreatePopulator();

       populator.PopulateMembership();  // Time consuming operation.
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        LoggingUtility.LogTrace(LoggingCategory.Membership, e);
     }
  }
```

**=> Class3.**

```
  /// <summary>
  /// The main implementation of the membership populator.
  /// </summary>
  public sealed class Populator : IDisposable, IMembershipPopulator
  {
     public void PopulateMembership()
     {
       // Code for some time consuming operations.
       // ........................................
       // ........................................
       // ........................................
     }
  }
```

}

Comment: Are you using the [Microsoft Sync Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Sync_Framework)?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, No, I am not using the MS Sync Framework.